# Cloud Kit Subscribe to CKRecord Created

Tags: ios, ios8, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckrecord

I have an iOS app I am working on using Cloud Kit. Basically what happens is that when a CKRecord gets deleted, the person who created the CKRecord in the first place should receive a notification. To do this, I am creating a subscription.

Everything seems to work the way it should, except it seems like whenever you create a record, you are actually subscribing to all records. Then it doesn't matter who created the record, because you will be notified. I think I am getting the NSPredicate wrong, maybe someone can help? Here is the code I have that is relevant:

```
    NSString *attributeName  = @"recordID";
    NSString *attributeValue = newRecord.recordID.recordName;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ like %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
    CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Photo" predicate:predicate options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion];
```

Now I get that the attributeName for recordId actually should be something like recordID.recordName, but I tried that as well and it didn't work. I am still getting the same result. I don't know the best way to do this, but basically what I want is the subscription to fire only to the creator of the CKRecord when that record has been deleted.

> Note that first I create the `CKRecord`, then upload it to CloudKit. Then in the callback method, I am subscribing and doing the code above.

Answer (score 2):

When you query a recordID field, then the attributeValue should also be a recordID and not as a string. Then for the attributeName filter you should not use %@ but %K

```
    NSString *attributeName  = @"recordID";
    CKRecordID *attributeValue = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithName:newRecord.recordID.recordName];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
    CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Photo" predicate:predicate options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion];
```

But when you have your logic like this, you will create a subscription for every record created. You could solve this by one generic subscription. Just add a condition for the metadata field creatorUserRecordID. You then do have to fetch the recordID of the loged in iCloud account first an d then create the subscription like this:

execute a fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler on the container. In the callback you will receive a recordID. just use that to create the filter

```
    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
            NSString *attributeName  = @"creatorUserRecordID";
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", attributeName, recordID];
           CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Photo" predicate:predicate options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion];
           // ... rest of your code
        }]
```

Just extend this code with error handling

Comment: Hi Edwin, I just tried your first solution, but it seems like I am still subscribing to EVERYTHING again... I make a record on two different iPhones with two different iTunes/iCloud accounts. Uploaded a diff record on each phone. When both were deleted using one phone, the other one received notifications for both. I would try your second approach, but I'm wondering why the first one isn't working?

Comment: I also tried:     NSString *attributeName  = @"recordID";
    CKRecordID *attributeValue = newRecord.recordID;    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", attributeName, attributeValue];    And it didn't work

Comment: I also noticed that on the CloudKit Dashboard, when I goto Subscription Types, I only see one with RecordType: Photo, Trigger: Remove, Criteria: (Blank)... I thought there would be a subscription for every record that gets created on there, and criteria of recordID has to be some long string?

Comment: Hi again Edwin, I just tried your second solution, and now when I try to subscribe I get an error: Unexpected expression: creatorUserRecordID LIKE <CKRecordID: 0x15c755580; _60078334fb8fe8f5ab957cf492dfbf3a:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>

Comment: Argh!... How could I have overlooked it. The predicate was using a like. For a CKRecordID query you should use == because it will always be an exact match. I corrected the answer for this.